# Creating memory mapped file and using it with fread on windows

Tags: winapi, memory-mapped-files

I want to create memory mapped file on windows (the method I know is  WINAPI's CreateFileMapping if there are other methods please mention them), then use fread to read from it, is it possible to read from it using fread? if it is possible,is it good programming? is it efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: The standard way to write to and read from memory (backed by a file mapping) is [memcpy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx). I have not the slightest clue, why you would want to use fread.

Comment: @IInspectable: Next up, I have a `FILE*` and wish to read from it using memcpy!

Answer (score 0):

`fread()` requires a `FILE*` to read from.

Once you have mapped the file into memory using `MapViewOfFile()`, you can wrap the memory pointer into a `FILE*` using [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html), if your compiler/rtl provides an implementation for it, or if you install a third-party implementation for your compiler.